# How can I get a touch event in .net Maui?

Tags: c#, maui, touch-event

I can not find a touch event handler for my .net maui application. The built-in gesture recognizer has a TapGesture. Google searches for this returned nothing. I asked ChatGPT which recommended using Effects from the Microsoft.Maui.Essentials kit. However, I can not even installed it because the platform type DotnetPlatform is incompatible with my project, but looking at the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/essentials/) it seems that this is useless LLVM advice.

How can I listen for a TouchBegin and TouchEnd event on a .net maui Frame?

Comment: Frame had (and probably still has) too many bugs. Use border instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implementing TouchTracking in .NET MAUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73994251/implementing-touchtracking-in-net-maui). FYI: This was the first hit returned by google `net maui touch tracking effects`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .NET MAUI, if you want to listen for specific touch events like
*TouchBegin* and *TouchEnd*, you might need to go a bit lower-level than the built-in gesture recognizers like TapGesture.

Here's a general approach to achieving this:

1. Custom Renderer Approach:
   The custom renderer approach allows you to use native controls and their features. By writing custom renderers for the Frame, you can capture native touch events.

**Code snippets are untested**

For Android:

```
using Android.Views;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;
using YourNamespace;
using FrameRenderer = Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.Platform.Android.FrameRenderer;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Frame), typeof(CustomFrameRenderer))]
namespace YourNamespace
{
    public class CustomFrameRenderer : FrameRenderer
    {
        public CustomFrameRenderer(Context context) : base(context) { }

        public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
        {
            if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Down)
            {
                // TouchBegin
            }
            else if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Up)
            {
                // TouchEnd
            }

            return base.OnTouchEvent(e);
        }
    }
}
```

For iOS:

```
using UIKit;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;
using YourNamespace;
using FrameRenderer = Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.Platform.iOS.FrameRenderer;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Frame), typeof(CustomFrameRenderer))]
namespace YourNamespace
{
    public class CustomFrameRenderer : FrameRenderer
    {
        public override void TouchesBegan(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
        {
            base.TouchesBegan(touches, evt);
            // TouchBegin
        }

        public override void TouchesEnded(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
        {
            base.TouchesEnded(touches, evt);
            // TouchEnd
        }
    }
}
```

2. Consider Using [SkiaSharp](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp):
   If your project uses or plans to use SkiaSharp for graphics, it also provides detailed touch event handlers.

Perhaps it wont help directly but hopefully put you on the right track. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try and report back